# How to change the interword spacing?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to enlarge the interword spacing, because with ITC Kabel's default spacing it's sometimes hard to decide where is the space between two words. I read the manual of the `microtype` package, and I did some trying, without success. For example this one:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[ spacing = {1000*,1666, } ]{ encoding = T1, family = *, shape=*,series=*}{ 25 }
```

Maybe there is an easy solution that doesn't involve `microtype`?.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the `\fontdimen` parameters controlling the interword spacing: `\fontdimen2` (the normal interword space), `\fontdimen3` (the amount of stretch of the interword space), and `\fontdimen4` (the amount of shrink). A lttle example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\spaceskip=1.5\fontdimen2\font plus 1.5\fontdimen3\font
minus 1.5\fontdimen4\font

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be clear about this example: we can set `\spaceskip` to set the interword glue, whose _default_ values (ideal, stretch, shrink) are picked up from the font's `(\fontdimen2, \fontdimen3, \fontdimen4)`.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/how-to-shorten-shrink-spaces-between-words

Answer (score 9):

If you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use the `WordSpace` option in `fontspec`:

```
\fontspec[WordSpace=1.0]{Times New Roman}
```

Comment: Thank you, that time I was using PDFLaTeX, but still thanks!

Comment: Please note that this only works while loading a font and not with `\addfontfeature`.