# control of word and line spacing in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, the spacing between words and lines inside tikz nodes are too much.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (9.,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7);

\draw [ultra thick, blue] (4.,4.4) +(-45:1.cm) node [black, xshift=1.4cm, yshift=-.28cm] {Demand of Imports} -- +(135:3.cm)  +(30:1.cm) node [black, xshift=1.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$Demand\ of\ Exports$} -- +(-150:4.2cm);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.92) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.68cm, yshift=.28cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.24cm, yshift=-.2cm]{$1.30$} -- +(130:.5cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-1.28cm, yshift=1.2cm, align=center] {Price\\buyers\\pay} -- ++(0:3.46);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.4) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.88cm, yshift=.06cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.44cm, yshift=0cm]{$1.00$} -- +(180:.4cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-2.cm, yshift=.06cm, align=center] {Price\\without\\tax} -- ++(0:4.);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.08) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.8cm, yshift=-.16cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.38cm, yshift=0cm]{$0.80$} -- +(-130:.5cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-1.28cm, yshift=-1.16cm, align=center] {Price\\sellers\\receive} -- ++(0:3.46);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to decrease these inter word/line spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use another font size with smaller baseline skip for the tikz image.

Never put text in math mode, one of the bad side effects is strange inter word spacing. If you want the words to be in italic, use `\textit{...}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\fontsize{11pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (9.,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7);

\draw [ultra thick, blue] (4.,4.4) +(-45:1.cm) node [black, xshift=1.4cm, yshift=-.28cm] {Demand of Imports} -- +(135:3.cm)  +(30:1.cm) node [black, xshift=1.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {\textit{Demand of Exports}} -- +(-150:4.2cm);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.92) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.68cm, yshift=.28cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.24cm, yshift=-.2cm]{$1.30$} -- +(130:.5cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-1.28cm, yshift=1.2cm, align=center,text width=1.5cm] {Price buyers pay} -- ++(0:3.46);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.4) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.88cm, yshift=.06cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.44cm, yshift=0cm]{$1.00$} -- +(180:.4cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-2.cm, yshift=.06cm, align=center,text width=1.5cm] {Price without tax} -- ++(0:4.);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.08) node [minimum size=4.cm, xshift=-.8cm, yshift=-.16cm, path picture={\draw [thick, black, solid, -latex'] (0,0) node [black, xshift=.38cm, yshift=0cm]{$0.80$} -- +(-130:.5cm);}]{} node [black, xshift=-1.28cm, yshift=-1.16cm, align=center,text width=1.5cm] {Price sellers receive} -- ++(0:3.46);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but for display reasons I do not want to decrease the font size. I used 2 examples one with plain text and the other with math mode just to show that both gave me extra inter word spacing.

Comment: @Hany I don't decrease the font size, I decrease the skip and while I think this is a bad idea, you asked for less space between the lines.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer controlled the inter-line spacing. What about the inter-word spacing.

Comment: @Hany The incorrectly used math mode is the only extra spacing I see. All the other spaces are of normal size and should IMHO not be decreased.

Comment: OK, forget about the math mode. Is there a way to decrease inter-word spacing.

Comment: @Hany You could add a negative dimension after `\\ `, e.g. `\\[-1mm]`, and replace spaces by thin spaces `\,` for instance.

Comment: @Hany I don't think that is a great idea, but you can fiddle with the font settings: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23921/35864. Especially if this is for a presentation the reduced space does not help the legibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers; I got what I needed.

Comment: @Hany `\fontdimen2` is a global value, so you should save its original value prior to redefining it and restore it later.