# How to customize the space between words?

Tags: spacing

I am new to Latex and currently use it to do my university homework. I wish to increase the space between words in my documents as they feel a bit choked, in my opinion.

I tried to look up on the web how to achieve this, but couldn't find any useful insight. I read [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX) article on Overleaf, but it only gave answers for paragraph and line spacing and not word spacing.

Is there an easy way to configure the word spacing to suit my taste?

Comment: Can you please provide a simplified version (i.e. pruned version) of your code, which we can copy&compile (i.e. is complete) AND shows your problem? A screenshot won't hurt spotting your trouble at a glance.

Comment: I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/how-to-shorten-shrink-spaces-between-words) may help you. You can check.

Comment: The `fontspec` package also lets you modify the interword spacing.

Comment: @CarLaTeX and @Krishna I looked at this post before, but it looked too low-level. I was hoping there is an easier solution like the `parskip` and `setspace` packages for paragraph and line spacing.

Comment: @ShaiAvr -- We have no idea what your text looks like now, and without that we can't do anything but guess.  That just wastes our time and yours.  Please add a small compilable example and output image as already requested.

Comment: @ShaiAvr in the linked question there are also more high-level solutions like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23927/, which mentions the `microtype` package that has a `\SetExtraSpacing` macro, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) on page 18.