# Is it possible to define the word stretch?

Tags: spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the interword spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/how-to-change-the-interword-spacing)

i would like to know if is possible to set the space between the words like i can do with the lines with `\baselinestretch`?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19236/3954.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can insert additional interword space using `\spaceskip`, e.g.

`\spaceskip 6pt plus 1pt minus 1pt`

The first value is the normal width of the resulting extra space, the second and third are the amounts by which it is allowed to grow and shrink, respectively. For comparison, you can enquire about the default interword spacing using `\the`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Default:
\the\fontdimen2\font\
plus
\the\fontdimen3\font\
minus
\the\fontdimen4\font

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\spaceskip 6pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal stretch of a specific length:

`Here\hspace{.5in}is a 0.5 inch space`

Stretch to fill whole line:

`Here is a \hfill stretched space`

Examples taken from Lamport's Manual.

Comment: I think Winter wants to adjust the limits used by the filling algorithm rather than wanting to install some space in any particular spot.

Comment: u are rigth dmckee :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
\setlength{\spaceskip}{Xpt plus Yfil}
```

(choose X and Y as you like)

Comment: I don't think putting a `fil` in `spaceskip` is a good idea.