# WordSpace factor does not increase again

Tags: spacing, fontspec

I am trying to understand how the `WordSpace` factor of `fontspecs`'s `\addfontfeatures` works. The word space is decreasing when I lower it, but not increasing when I increase the factor again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Ein paar Wörter.

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.9,LetterSpace=0}Ein paar Wörter.}

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.7,LetterSpace=0}Ein paar Wörter.}

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.3,LetterSpace=0}Ein paar Wörter.}

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.7,LetterSpace=0}Ein paar Wörter.}

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.9,LetterSpace=0}Ein paar Wörter.}

Ein paar Wörter.
\end{document}
```

My application for it is to selectively squeeze some lines of verse to avoid a line break, or a paragraph in order to avoid widows and orphans, but I became aware of the fact that I cannot really control the factor and thus keep getting smaller word space. How do I increase the word space factor again?

[image: output]

EDIT: As suggested by egreg `\spaceskip` looks like a good way of doing this indeed. Just that I also have to take care of any `\textsl` and similar passages contained in the stretch of text to be adjusted, and that when reducing the inter word space quite a bit also the extra spaces after punctuation should be adjusted, via `\xspaceskip`.

Comment: You should use `\spaceskip` instead of setting `WordSpace`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256025/local-application-of-addfontfeature-and-wordspace-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordspace changes the current fontdimen by the factor you give. You can see the settings in the log-file:

```
   . \fontdimen 2\font =.2\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =.2\fontdimen
. 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =.2\fontdimen 4\font
```

So if you want to increase it again you must use values larger then one.

As egreg wrote the settings are global. This effect is partly hidden in your example with the `LetterSpace` option which has the actual effect to load a new font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Ein paar Wörter.

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=.2}Ein paar Wörter.}

Ein paar Wörter.

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=5}Ein paar Wörter.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To show the effect of additional options here an example with color. As you see the wordspace of black and red font are adapted independently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Ein paar Wörter.

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=.2,Color=red}Ein paar Wörter.}

Ein paar Wörter.

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=5}Ein paar Wörter.}

{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=5,Color=red}Ein paar Wörter.}
\end{document}
```

[image]