# Special spaces in LaTeX

Tags: spacing

I need special hard spaces for example i need 0.33em, 0.5em, 1em, hair etc. spaces.

Also i need a normal spaces (word spacing) in 0.25em to 0.75em.

How to do it?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Do you want to change the spacing between 2 adjacent characters in a word?

Comment: Please do not cast downvotes this quickly for questions that aren't spam or offensive. Usually, we allow some time (e.g. a day) for the poster to edit their question with more information. Also, if you cast the first vote, please also leave a comment explaining your reason to do so.

Comment: Probably you need [How to change the interword spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19236/19356).

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide some context.  What is the situation in which you want to have these spaces?  Could you provide an example where you would like to have these spaces appear?

Comment: (Jake's comment also applies to votes-to-close, not just down-votes.)

Comment: Adorable Creature your solution is good. I wanted to do it for all text.

Answer (score 8):

For getting "hard coded" space between two words, independently on inputs such as

```
word\hard{2em}word
word \hard{2em}word
word \hard{2em} word
```

just define

```
\newcommand{\hard}[1]{\unskip\hspace{#1}\ignorespaces}
```

Thus spaces input before `\hard` will be nullified by `\unskip`, the following ones by `\ignorespaces`.

In order to change the default interword space in a paragraph, use the primitive `\spaceskip`:

```
\newenvironment{myiwspace}[1][0.75em]
  {\spaceskip=#1\relax\ignorespaces}
  {\unskip}
```

so you can write

```
This is a part of the paragraph with normal space
\begin{myiwspace}
and this is a part with $0.75$\,em space between words;
\end{myiwspace}
this has normal space,
\begin{myiwspace}[2.5em]
while this part will have $2.5$\,em space between words,
\end{myiwspace}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For really hard (i.e. non-shrinkable, non-stretchable) spaces —something that could upset a bit the justification algorithm if you want to use it as word separator— `\hspace{length}` is the way to go.

Otherwise, you can use glues to allow some variation : `\hskip 1em plus .1em minus .1em`.

As far as inter-word spacing is concerned, this is decided by the font ; the low-level `\fontdimen` parameter 2 specifies the inter-word spacing, the 3 the stretching and the 4 the shrinking.

Answer (score 2):

With `\hspace{length}` you can specify the length of a horizontal space.

Comment: I tried that, but something like that: "word \hspace{1em} word" works diffrent like something like that: "word\hspace{1em} word". Im not sure but i think that second example work not properly to and i have 1em+some space from space :)

Comment: omit the spaces between the words and the command. Try this: "word\hspace{2em}word". Otherwise LaTeX typesets after 'word' an ordinary space plus a fixed space plus an ordinary space and then the next word.

Comment: Ok its good and cleaver solution.