# Letterspaced texttyper text with identical width for inter-word spaces

Tags: spacing, microtype, letterspacing

I like to use LaTeX to place some text on top of an existing PDF form, so I don't have to fill it out by hand. For this I'm using `microtype`s letterspacing feature to stretch the upper-case text across the character boxes of the form.
This works well when `tt` font is used, except if I have a space in the text. Then the space seems to have a shorter width which makes all following characters to be to far to the left so they are touching the box lines, which I try to avoid.

How can I make `microtype` to make the inter-word spaces inside `\textls` the same as a normal `tt` character?

Alternatively, is there a way to have monospaced text while using a different font, like `\sffamily`?

As this code is a prototype for a form-fillout package I have in mind some manual adjustments like breaking the words appart and placing them separatly is not suitable for me.

Example Form:

See the misplaced second first name (MANFRED) and country name (MUSTERLAND) when there is a space beforehand.

[image]

Example Code:

```
\documentclass[multi=page,border=0,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\edef\tempbox{\csname @tempboxa\endcsname}%
\sbox\tempbox{\includegraphics[page=1]{formular.pdf}}%
\begin{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\wd\tempbox,y=-\ht\tempbox]
\iffalse
\draw [ultra thin,black!10] (0,0) grid [step=2mm] (1, 1);
\draw [very thin,black!50] (0,0) grid [step=1cm] (1, 1);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmax{\wd\tempbox/1cm}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymax{\ht\tempbox/1cm}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\xmax} \node [font=\sffamily\tiny, anchor=north west] at (\n cm, 0) {\n} ;
\foreach \n in {1,...,\ymax} \node [font=\sffamily\tiny, anchor=north west] at (0, -\n cm) {\n} ;
\fi
\node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {\usebox\tempbox};
%\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.1\wd\tempbox,ystep=0.1\ht\tempbox] (1, 1);
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

\begin{scope}[x=1cm, y=-1cm,anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\SetTracking{ encoding = *}{ 618 }
\def\placetext#1#2{\node at (#1) {\textls{\MakeUppercase{#2}}};}
\node [inner sep=0pt] at (7.75, 8.825) {$\times$};
%\node [inner sep=0pt] at (8.675, 8.825) {$\times$};
\placetext{2.6, 9.4}{MUSTERMAN}
\placetext{2.6, 10.25}{MAX MANFRED}
\placetext{2.6, 11.1}{MUSTERSTRASSE}
\placetext{16.7, 11.1}{1234}
\placetext{2.6, 11.95}{98765}
\placetext{5.5, 11.95}{MUSTERSTADT, Musterland}
\placetext{2.6, 12.8}{12}
\placetext{3.75, 12.8}{34}
\placetext{4.85, 12.8}{5678}
\placetext{7.15, 12.8}{MUSTERSTADT}

\placetext{2.6, 16.925}{MUSTERSTRASSE}
\placetext{16.7, 16.925}{1234}
\placetext{2.6, 17.85}{98765}
\placetext{5.1725, 17.85}{MUSTERSTADT}
\placetext{2.6, 18.75}{\MakeUppercase{max.mustermann@web.de}}

\node [inner sep=0pt] at (2.615, 19.725) {\Large$\times$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{page}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example cannot be compiled.

Comment: @egreg: You mean without the PDF form itself, right? Well, I did not want to post it because I don't have the copyright on it. I actually thought the problem is described well enough to get the idea what I want and the example code is there to show my general approach. I didn't had the time yet to make a dummy form myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added `[spacing = {1200*,,}]` as optional argument to `\SetTracking`. For the choice of `1200` I took my lead from @StevenSegletes's answer, after some trial and error with starting point microtype doc example top page 17 `MICRO FINE TUNING : Tracking`

```
\documentclass[multi=page,border=0,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\edef\tempbox{\csname @tempboxa\endcsname}%
\sbox\tempbox{\fboxsep-\fboxrule\fbox{\vbox to 29.7cm{\hsize21cm\noindent X\dotfill X\par
                    \vfill\noindent X\dotfill X\par}}}%
\begin{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\wd\tempbox,y=-\ht\tempbox]
\iffalse
\draw [ultra thin,black!10] (0,0) grid [step=2mm] (1, 1);
\draw [very thin,black!50] (0,0) grid [step=1cm] (1, 1);
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmax{\wd\tempbox/1cm}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymax{\ht\tempbox/1cm}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\xmax} \node [font=\sffamily\tiny, anchor=north west] at (\n cm, 0) {\n} ;
\foreach \n in {1,...,\ymax} \node [font=\sffamily\tiny, anchor=north west] at (0, -\n cm) {\n} ;
\fi
\node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {\usebox\tempbox};
%\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [xstep=0.1\wd\tempbox,ystep=0.1\ht\tempbox] (1, 1);
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

\begin{scope}[x=1cm, y=-1cm,anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\SetTracking[spacing = {1200*,,}]{ encoding = *, }{ 618 }
\def\placetext#1#2{\node at (#1) {\textls{\MakeUppercase{#2}}};}
\node [inner sep=0pt] at (7.75, 8.825) {$\times$};
%\node [inner sep=0pt] at (8.675, 8.825) {$\times$};
\placetext{2.6, 9.4}{MUSTERMAN}
\placetext{2.6, 10.25}{MAX MANFRED}
\placetext{2.6, 11.1}{MUSTERSTRASSE}
\placetext{16.7, 11.1}{1234}
\placetext{2.6, 11.95}{98765}
\placetext{5.5, 11.95}{MUSTERSTADT, Musterland}
\placetext{2.6, 12.8}{12}
\placetext{3.75, 12.8}{34}
\placetext{4.85, 12.8}{5678}
\placetext{7.15, 12.8}{MUSTERSTADT}

\placetext{2.6, 16.925}{MUSTERSTRASSE}
\placetext{16.7, 16.925}{1234}
\placetext{2.6, 17.85}{98765}
\placetext{5.1725, 17.85}{MUSTERSTADT}
\placetext{2.6, 18.75}{\MakeUppercase{max.mustermann@web.de}}

\node [inner sep=0pt] at (2.615, 19.725) {\Large$\times$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{page}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks good within the form. Sorry for not providing it, but it's tricky regarding copyright etc. Anyway, could you just add a short description on top to explain what you changed (so far as I see it, adding `[spacing = {1200*,,}]` to `\SetTracking`), so that others with the same problem don't have to compare codes. Thanks.

Comment: yes, sorry will add description.

Answer (score 3):

I took the lead from this question: [How to change the interword spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/how-to-change-the-interword-spacing) and modified `\spaceskip`, to expand by a factor of 1.2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\def\placetext#1{\textls{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\placetext{x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x} (wrong)

\placetext{xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyx}

{\spaceskip=1.2\fontdimen2\font plus 1.2\fontdimen3\font minus 1.2\fontdimen4\font

\placetext{x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x} (fixed)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\spaceskip` can be incorporated into the macro definition itself, and grouped to limit its scope:

```
\def\placetext#1{{%
  \spaceskip=1.2\fontdimen2\font plus 1.2\fontdimen3\font minus 1.2\fontdimen4\font%
  \textls{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
}}
```