# Adding more space between words in tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

Here is the code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,hebrew,american]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[x11names,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=gray!30!white,boxrule=1pt,colframe=blue!75!white,fonttitle=\bfseries} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[valign=center,halign=center,colback=gray!50,drop large lifted shadow=BurlyWood!70,fit basedim=7pt,left=1mm, right=1mm] \bfseries\tcbfontsize{6}
AAA AAA AAA      
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

How do I get more space between those words?
**I'm looking for a command or something like it, because I use this as a environment at LyX, so I want it to be automatically**

P.S. There are many ways to change the font size. But no matter which way - the result is the same....

Thank you!

Comment: It appears to relate to inter-word spacing. Please have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19240/164314). You can probably issue a `\spaceskip=1.5\fontdimen2\font plus 1.5\fontdimen3\font minus 1.5\fontdimen4\font` at the beginning of the `tcolorbox` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want an automatic solution in LyX, I propose implementing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19240/164314) by @GonzaloMedina as follows: Add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{%
  \spaceskip=1.5\fontdimen2\font plus 1.5\fontdimen3\font minus 1.5\fontdimen4\font
}
```

to your customized preamble (after `\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}`, of course). You may adjust the three `1.5`’s to whatever numbers you find appropriate.

**Added**: The inter-word space, `\spaceskip`, is a glue which consists of 1) a fixed “ideal” length, taken from `\fontdimen2\font`; 2) a stretch length, taken from `\fontdimen3\font`; and 3) a shrink length, taken from `\fontdimen4\font`. These values are set up by the font designers and **you normally shouldn’t change them**. To increase `\spaceskip`, we can simply multiply each of the three lengths by a factor we want. In the above example, we are telling TeX to use inter-word space `1.5` times the original, with `1.5` times the stretchability and shrinkability. Also, the change happens inside `tcolorbox`, which makes it *local*.

Comment: Can you explain me more about the numbers (what they mean)?  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @heblyx Answer updated. :)