# Constant word spacing

Tags: spacing, luatex

is there a way to achieve constant word spacing in paragraph using latex/ luatex/ xelatex/ context? I came across posts that mention Tex applies glue between words, but am not sure how to exactly control them, if at all it’s possible (am more hopeful that there is a lualatex way of doing that). I guess it can be achieved in InDesign by specifying same value for minimum, desirable, and maximum: https://creativepro.com/the-complete-guide-to-word-spacing/

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Please show us an example of your problem. Do not add external links as it may go dead over time.

Comment: The `ragged2e` package may help. `\raggedright` too, but `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` is likely to find better-looking line breaks.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/how-to-change-the-interword-spacing and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/how-to-shorten-shrink-spaces-between-words

Comment: If you fix the space between words, then your justification alignment went wrong, so please confirm whether you require both justification with space fixing or only space fixing?

Comment: Take also in mind `\parfillskip`, `\emergencystretch` and the `microtype` package.

Comment: Note also word spacing in InDesign is a paragraph property, while in TeX it's a font property (which, for me, usually makes a lot more sense).

Answer (score 1):

Really constant word spacing seems very hard to get, but however, there is an aspect of how we observe the distance between the last letter of a word and the first of the following one.

In the picture below in the last or second last line the distance between »of« and »words« seems smaller compared to »match« and »the«.

I played around a bit with the rich options the fontspec package offers. The option `OpticalSize` has an effect, while the justifying and RaggedRight environments of the ragged2e package don't.

However, you will need a broad right margin, because the usual word wrap doesn't word, if the stretch and the shrink of the interword space become zero, as with `WordSpace={1,0,0}`.

```
\documentclass[english, fontsize=14pt, parskip=full, usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{roboto-mono}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[right=5cm]{geometry}
%\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\fontspec{FiraSans-Regular.otf}[WordSpace={1,0,0}, PunctuationSpace=0, Kerning=Off,
OpticalSize=0]

\blindtext

\ttfamily{}
\fontspec{RobotoMono-Regular.otf}[WordSpace={.5,0,0}, PunctuationSpace=0,
%OpticalSize=0
]

%\fontspec{RobotoMono-Regular.otf}
\blindtext

\fontspec{RobotoMono-Regular.otf}[WordSpace={.5,0,0}, PunctuationSpace=0,
OpticalSize=0
]
%\begin{RaggedRight}
  \blindtext{}
%\end{RaggedRight}

\end{document}
```

[image: printout pic]